# Flash redirect and download file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is it possible to create a flash file hosted on page1.com and embedded on page2.com that redirects to page1.com? If yes than how?
And is it possible to create a flash file that starts a download automatic without user action? Im using Adobe flash professional CS5 and Actionscript 3.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  Maybe clarify what you mean by "embedded on page2.com".  Any sample HTML code would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question: is it possible to create a flash file that starts a download automatic without user action?

i didnt understand the first part of your question but to answer your second half it is possible to start downloading automatically, conditional they have flash installed to their browser but downloading automatically can ownly really stream vids or music,pics,text files or another swf. other files will ask for computer permission.